# How to scrape the product information from the page using Beautiful Soup in which html table are involved

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-tableextract

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://books.toscrape.com/'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://books.toscrape.com/' )
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
productlinks=[]
Title=[]
Brand=[]
tra = soup.find_all('article',class_='product_pod')
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True)[1:]:
        comp=baseurl+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)

for link in productlinks:
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    try:
        title=soup.find('h3').text
    except:
        title=' '
    Title.append(title)
    price=soup.find('p',class_="price_color").text.replace('£','').replace(',','').strip()
    Brand.append(price)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    
    {"Title": Title, "Price": price}
)
print(df)
```

The above script was working as expected but I want scrape inforamtion of each  product such as`upc`, `product type`
**example** to get information of these single page
https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html
to scrape `upc` ,`product type` etc... all other information lies in **product information**

Comment: I don't see any code that attempts to operate on multiple pages. What have you tried in this area so far?

Comment: Please fix your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `start=` parameter in URL to get next pages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(0, 10):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    r = requests.get(
        "https://pk.indeed.com/jobs?q=&l=Lahore&start={}".format(page * 10)
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find_all("h2", class_="jobTitle")

    for i in title:
        print(i.text)
```

Prints:

```
Data Entry Work Online
newAdmin Assistant
newNCG Agent
Data Entry Operator
newResearch Associate Electrical
Administrative Assistant (Executive Assistant)
Admin Assistant Digitally
newIT Officer (Remote Work)
OFFICE ASSISTANT
Cash Officer - Lahore Region
newDeputy Manager Finance
Admin Assistant
Lab Assistant
newProduct Portfolio & Customer Service Specialist
Front Desk Officer
newRelationship Manager, Recovery
MANAGEMENT TRAINEE PROGRAM
Email Support Executive (International)
Data Entry Operator
Admin officer

...and so on.
```